# porting pintOS to Raspberry-pi

Tags: operating-system, raspberry-pi, pintos

For a 6 months long project, i was thinking to write [PintOS](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/10wi-cs140/pintos/pintos.html#SEC_Contents)  like OS for raspberry-pi. Since i am a beginner, having no practical knowledge of operating system, i thought of start with porting (PintOS) rather than writing OS of my own. My questions are:

1. **How to proceed , i.e. what are the things i should know before starting porting.** (I have knowledge of assembly, theoretical concepts of OS, boot sequence overview, etc).
2. Will cross-compiling the source code is enough?.
3. How far is this project worth doing for 6 months(answer depends on 1st question :p)?

Here are some similar work i have found :

[Porting the Embedded Xinu
Operating System to the Raspberry Pi](http://digitalcommons.macalester.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1035&context=mathcs_honors)

P.S. I am an undergraduate student.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on PintOS in my time at grad school, so I speak from experience.

I can probably answer your questions but it might be too late since I just came across Pintos section of stackoverflow.

1. You will need to know ARM instruction set since you will be translating all X86 machine instructions to equivalent ARM machine instructions in the vanilla PintOS source code.
2. My guess is no, you can't just cross compile the code  because of 1.
3. Also depends how much you know ARM instructions.

Hope it helps!